# Can someone explain the first lines of code of the jQuery library?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know about IIFEs but I can't understand the first 50 lines of code of the jQuery library. Can someone explain the logic behind it?

```js
( function( global, factory ) {

 "use strict";

 if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {

  // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like environments where a proper `window`
  // is present, execute the factory and get jQuery.
  // For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
  // (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
  // This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
  // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
  // See ticket #14549 for more info.
  module.exports = global.document ?
   factory( global, true ) :
   function( w ) {
    if ( !w.document ) {
     throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
    }
    return factory( w );
   };
 } else {
  factory( global );
 }

// Pass this if window is not defined yet
} )( typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {
```

Comment: Its an IIFE with 2 params. The purpose of it is included in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Now days JS libraries can be used in browser as well as Nodejs environment. Since there is a major difference between these environments, JQuery tries to make it compatible with all the environments. Rest, I think is mentioned in comments in code itself,

Comment: Where does that variable `module` come from?

Comment: `module` is inbuilt in JS modules used by NodeJS and Webpack.